# Drawing Rectangles in Java

Tags: java, oop, rectangles

I am trying to draw rectangles in Java like this picture:

[image]

I visualize the coordinates as I do at math but I come up with the rectangles turned upside down which is like this:

[image]

I know Im missing just a few things.What should I do?
(Colors will be edited)

```
 public class BlockTower
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(20, 70, 40, 30);
    rect1.draw();
    rect1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    rect1.fill();

    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(60, 70, 40, 30);
    rect2.draw();
    rect2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    rect2.fill();

    Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(100, 70, 40, 30);
    rect3.draw();
    rect3.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    rect3.fill();

    Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(40, 100, 40, 30);
    rect4.draw();
    rect4.setColor(Color.RED);
    rect4.fill();

    Rectangle rect5 = new Rectangle(80, 100, 40, 30);
    rect5.draw();
    rect5.setColor(Color.PINK);
    rect5.fill();

    Rectangle rect6 = new Rectangle(60, 130, 40, 30);
    rect6.draw();
    rect6.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    rect6.fill();



    //TODO finish the draft to display the six blocks
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to Android?

Comment: As I know that Android is based on Java.

Comment: @S.Sahin Your question could be classified as java question because there is no connection with android. Just pure java code.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates in Swing start from **Top Left**. That means you have to recalculate your y-coordinates. So the bottom of your panel is actually at the current `height`.

[image]

If you've calculated something to be at coordinates `(x,y)` it now has to be at coordinates `(x, height - y)` instead.

Comment: Now I get it thanks.I need to ask something.Whats wrong with my question? I am not comfortable asking questions here.When I post a new question people starts complaining and downvoting.

Comment: @S.Sahin Part of the problem with this question in particular, is the fact that the documentation and available tutorials would have answered your question, or at least provided you with the enough information to ascertain the cause of your problem. There's also little or no information about the APIs you are using, it's impossible from the code to determine if you're using a third party API, Swing, AWT, GWT or some other framework